# My dropbox and network indicators moved to the bottom panel

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel

I log in and now my Dropbox and network indicators are on the bottom panel just right of center.  Instead of the top panel just left of the time.  I do not know why they moved or how to put them back.  Even if I wanted them on the lower panel, I would not want them nearly centered.  Clicking or right clicking or attempting to drag to the top panel just opens my Dropbox folder or my network menu.  How can I get them where I want them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the applet you are looking at is `notification-area-applet` try right clicking somewhere in space aound the icons[you may see a separator line near icons try right clicking on that rather than icon itself] and see it will give you option to remove it. I use unity nowadays so I forgot if there is gui for adding/removing applets in gnome. So try right clicking on the panel itself and see if there is an option to remove from panel, I remember there is an option to add to panel. So, right click on top panel and choose add to panel and search for `notification-area-applet` and add it and move it your desired location.

Comment: I was able to remove it from the bottom.  But it would not let me add it to the top.  So I restarted and it was back at the bottom.  I set the bottom panel as a right panel and then it would let me move them up the right side to the top.  I felt problem solved.  I reset it to be on the bottom again and my notifications were still at the top.  I rebooted to make sure all was well and they are at the bottom again.

Comment: I got it to move to the top by unlocking everything on both panels.  Then I right clicked near as you suggested and chose move.  It is staying on the top panel but every time I login it is in a seemingly random location on the top panel.  It makes no difference if I lock it to the panel or not.

Comment: you need to lock everything not just the single one, just move and place everything where you desire then lock it. You may have invisible separators as well see that they are locked to panel as well.

Comment: I did that and it reset its locked status and moved again.  When I was double checking that all were locked, I accidentally removed my weather applet.  I put it back.  Now the notifications stay put.  Weird!

Comment: Spoke too soon, they moved again.  Three logins down the road